# Alternative for cd in Shell Scripting

Tags: macos, shell

As far as I know its not advisable to use cd in shell scripting. I know about pushd. But could not find a way to move backwards. Suppose currently i am in

```
/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/finalDiskCleanUp/script/month
```

and I want to move to

```
/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/finalDiskCleanUp/logs
```

How can it be done. I tried to use popd but its not working. Any alternative method.

Comment: Please explain why you wouldn't use `cd` in a shell script and how `pushd` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, just not quite there yet. Have a look at this example:

```
AnAppleADay:~ KeepsTheDoctorAway$ pushd /Users/KeepsTheDoctorAway/Downloads/
~/Downloads ~
AnAppleADay:Downloads KeepsTheDoctorAway$ popd
~
AnAppleADay:~ KeepsTheDoctorAway$
```

The premise behind `pushd` and `popd` is that you push a folder to the stack, and then when you're done, you pop it off the stack, returning you to your starting point.

To get to `/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/finalDiskCleanUp/logs` from `/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/finalDiskCleanUp/script/month`, all you need to do is

1. Push the directory to the stack with `pushd /Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/finalDiskCleanUp/logs`
2. When that's done, pop it off the stack with `popd`

Comment: Good explanation, with example. One would think that `man pushd` and `man popd` would provide this sort of information but unfortunately they don't.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` come with some of the same warnings as `cd` -- if anything goes wrong, you can wind up with parts of your script executing in unexpected places. **Always** check for errors when changing directories in a script, and if you don't have a good way to recover, it's probably better to exit with an error than continue executing in the wrong place.